# Mixing OutputCache and Dynamic Range Requests in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jplayer, lib.web.mvc

I'm using the [`RangeFilePathResult`](http://tpeczek.blogspot.ca/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html) class to serve mp3 files from an MVC controller.

The action is defined as follows:

```
[CacheFilter]
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Mp3Cache")]
public RangeFilePathResult Mp3Completed(string f)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(string.Format("C:\\test\\{0}.mp3", f));
    return new RangeFilePathResult("audio/mpeg", info.FullName, info.LastWriteTimeUtc, info.Length);
}
```

And the cache policy as follows:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="Mp3Cache" duration="3600" varyByParam="f" location="Any" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Why does this work correctly as is? It seems that you would need explicit `varyByHeader` to ensure that range requests work with output caching? The problem I was addressing was that jPlayer on iOS would be unable to display the duration of MP3 files and would render NaN when served with with a traditional FilePathResult - it works under this implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing here is that the response to range request is not typical **200 OK** but **206 Partial Content**.

In case of **206 Partial Content** several additional conditions must be met:

- The request must have included a `Range` header field indicating the desired range, and may have included an `If-Range` header field to make the request conditional
- The response must include either a `Content-Range` header field indicating the range included with this response, or a `multipart/byteranges` `Content-Type` including `Content-Range` fields for each part.
- The response must include `ETag` and/or `Content-Location` (if the header would have been sent in a 200 response to the same request)
- The response must include `Date`

Now every caching mechanism (in case of `location="Any"` this is browser, proxy server and your hosting IIS) which supports HTTP protocol must know that **206 Partial Content** is different than **200 OK** and treat it accordingly. Below you can find most important rules of caching **206 Partial Content** response:

- Cache must not combine a 206 response with other previously cached content if the `ETag` or `Last-Modified` headers do not match exactly
- Cache that does not support the `Range` and `Content-Range` headers must not cache 206 responses

To summary this up, you don't need to use `varyByHeader` because every cache which follows HTTP protocol knows that in case of **206 Partial Content** the `Range` and `Content-Range` headers are part of variant.